# field not found in type cassandra.Config in loki yaml file

Tags: cassandra, grafana, grafana-loki

Below is the config i have in my config.yaml

```
  storageConfig:
    cassandra:
      endpoint: https://api-test/v1/apps/tables/blobTable/blobs/
      client_cert: |

      client_key: |

      keyspace: loki
      table: logs
      batch_size: 1000
      batch_timeout: 1s
      max_retries: 3
```

I'm getting below errors

```
failed parsing config: /etc/loki/config/config.yaml: yaml: unmarshal errors:  
line 75: field batch_size not found in type cassandra.Config  
line 76: field batch_timeout not found in type cassandra.Config  
line 77: field client_cert not found in type cassandra.Config  
line 142: field client_key not found in type cassandra.Config  
line 173: field endpoint not found in type cassandra.Config  
line 176: field table not found in type cassandra.Config
```

From the official docs i couln't find the endpoint option in cassandra but from chatgpt i got that config.

Am i missing something in config ? Or endpoint is not at all allowed ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look for `cassandra` in the docs, you'll find all the available configuration options for that storage.
https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/configuration/#storage_config